# Можно ли использовать имя своего блога в имени пользователя?

Tags: обсуждение

Поменял имя на адрес своего блога.
Такое вообще разрешается или необходимо вернуть всё как было?
Спасибо.

Comment: А чем не угодило указание сайта в профиле? Там же поле соответствующее есть. А так — складывается впечатление, будто не с человеком разговариваешь, а с абстрактным обезличенным *сайтом*. Малоприятно и неуютно.

Comment: складывается впечатление, что **1** - это бот, **2**- это спаммер, **3**-участник нехитрым способом пытается привлечь пользователей на сайт) Личный вопрос - **а зачем это Вам?** Сомневаюсь, что просто так.

Comment: @Alex, так очевидно _нехитрым способом пытается привлечь пользователей на сайт_

Comment: @Grundy это шанс сознаться )

Comment: Вроде бы не запрещается, наверняка создаст сколько-то дополнительных посещений сайта, но немного портит впечатления от общения. Представьте, что Stack Overflow основали не Джоэл Спольски и Джефф Этвуд, а joelonsoftware.com и codinghorror.com. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, coding horror - в самый раз)))

Comment: @Qwertiy чувство юмора у Джеффа явно присутствует. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Псевдоним на сайте – это лично дело каждого, как и раздел «Обо мне», до тех пор, пока в нем нет оскорблений любого вида. Важно понимать, что псевдоним – это ваша подпись к публикуемым сообщениям. Если вы ассоциируете себя с каким-либо продуктом расположенным по адресу в вашем псевдониме – пожалуйста!

В дополнение, обратите внимание на страницу справки «[Какое поведение ожидается от участников?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)»